# PHP nightly: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, travis-ci

I am seeing [UT failures](https://travis-ci.org/emeraldion/creso/jobs/181354791) in [a PHP webapp](https://github.com/emeraldion/creso) running in Travis CI against PHP nightly:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.2.0-dev (cli) (built: Dec  4 2016 22:49:34) ( ZTS )
```

This is the failing test case:

```
$payments = PaymentsHelper::refunds('DE0000000001', '2016-04-01', '2017-04-01');

$this->assertNotNull($payments);
$this->assertEquals(0, count($payments));
```

Test failure

```
1) PaymentsHelperTest::test_refunds_within_lifetime
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

The code being tested at the moment contains debug logging showing the return value of `refunds()` is indeed an Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Payment Object
        (
...
        )
)
```

Am I hitting a bug in PHP nightly?

Comment: Maybe - but it shouldn't be surprising that an unreleased version of the PHP interrupter isn't production ready. Even still, showing a failing unit test for *your* class isn't sufficient evidence to accuse PHP of being wrong. I'd first throughly investigate the possibility you just broke your code on the last commit.

Comment: I debugged the issue further and realized the error happens earlier in code, where a dependency returns a `NULL` and the code calls `count(NULL)`. PHP 7.2.0-dev is now less forgiving on its input apparently.

Answer (score 3):

I debugged the issue further and realized the error happens earlier in code, where a dependency returns a `NULL` and the code calls `count(NULL)`:

```
$bonds = $bond_factory->find_all(/* ... */);
if (count($bonds) > 0)
{
  //...
}
```

I resolved guarding the call to `count()` with a null check:

```
$bonds = $bond_factory->find_all(/* ... */);
if (!is_null($bonds) && count($bonds) > 0)
{
  //...
}
```

PHP 7.2.0-dev is now less forgiving on its input apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Another way for pass warning..

```
if ( count( $bonds ? : [] ) ) { .... }
```